# EFI boot partition mounted at /media/[user]

Tags: permissions, mount, external-hdd

Upon having problems with permissions for an external drive, I discovered my /dev/sda1 EFI boot partition had been mounted at /media/[username]. The partition was also still mounted at /boot/EFI.

This restricted access to all external drives automatically mounted at /media/[username] to root, which is highly undesirable.

How would I go about safely unmounting this new mountpoint, without somehow messing up my boot partition?

Answer (score 0):

For later reference, a reboot of the machine made the boot partition mount at /boot/EFI as usual, and it did not mount at /media/[user].

This made external drives accessible again, with no need to chown anything within /media.